# Integrated webcam not working Ubuntu 22.04 getting error uvcvideo 1-6:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19)

Tags: ubuntu, usb, camera

It is a lenovo ideapad dual boot system with Ubuntu and Kali. Webcam is not accessible, it is showing blank, the light blips and goes off. Tried it with Cheese, browsers, guvcview, zoom and teams. It shows 'integrated camera c' in the settings but output remains blank.

Few things which I've tried and their output `uvcvideo 1-6:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19)

```
dmesg | grep video

[ 41.778881] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00 

[ 42.298170] ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes rom: no post: no) 

[ 42.534287] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo 

[ 952.321442] uvcvideo 1-6:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19). 

[ 952.325434] uvcvideo 1-6:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19). 

[ 952.329433] uvcvideo 1-6:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19). 

[ 952.333433] uvcvideo 1-6:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
```

also while trying to use Cheese

```
(cheese:9675): dconf-WARNING **: 03:47:50.976: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)

(cheese:9675): cheese-WARNING **: 03:47:51.275: Could not read from resource.: ../sys/v4l2/gstv4l2bufferpool.c(1181): gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_poll (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin18/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src1: poll error 1: Invalid argument (22)`
```

Also tried

chmod 666 /dev/video*

but problem remained unsolved.

Comment: I'm removing the [tag:kali-linux] tag, because the fact that you can also boot another operating system than the one where the problem occurs is probably not helpful in categorizing your question. You mention that you dual-boot Kali in the question, though, so if there's actually something that depends on that, it's still there.

Comment: bad news is that this might simply be a bug in the camera firmware that crashes for *some* reason.